JUnit4 code coverage issue with Exception expected
I have the following sample class in Java:
package main;

public class SampleClass {
    private String id;

    public SampleClass(String id) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        validation(id);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void validation(String inputId) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (inputId.length() != 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid length");
        }
    }
}


And now, I'm trying to test the code with JUnit4 tests like the following:
package main;

import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

public class Test {

    @org.junit.Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @org.junit.Test
    public void normalTest() {
        SampleClass sample = new SampleClass("123456");
    }

    @org.junit.Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void lengthTestOriginal() {
        SampleClass sample = new SampleClass("1234567");
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void lengthTestVersion1() {
        thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
        thrown.expectMessage("Invalid length");
        SampleClass sample = new SampleClass("12345");
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void lengthTestVersion2() {
        try {
            SampleClass puerto2 = new SampleClass("1234567");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("Invalid length", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

However, when I run the JUnit tests with coverage, the SampleClass() instantiations that must throw an exception seem to not being covered, as shown in the image:

I know the tool may not be able to detect such code as covered, as discussed here, however, is the any way to write the tests so that they show as covered? As you can see I tried several alternative ways to perform the same test, all of them failing to be covered in the same instantiation line.

There is no need to declare a variable, and that is probably what makes your coverage tool consider it not covered, because the method ends abruptly before it can assign a value to the declared variable. Just replace SampleClass sample = new SampleClass("1234567"); with new SampleClass("1234567"); (and similar for the puerto2 case).

@mark-rotteveel Still considers it as not covered.

Then I'd say the Eclipse code coverage tooling is a bit peculiar.

You show the coverage of the test class, not the coverage of the class under test, which is 100%. If you want your test case classes to have 100% coverage, you must write test cases for your test cases, and there's no end to that. But be my guest ;)


You don't need to write numerous test cases to verify if an exception is thrown. A single test case is sufficient to confirm the expected exception is raised under specific conditions.

Example:
public class SampleClassTest {
  @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void testWhenExpectedLengthIsGreaterThan6_thenShouldThrowIllegalArgumentException() {
    final SampleClass sample = new SampleClass("1234567");
    sample.validation("invalid length");
  }

  @Test
  public void testWhenExpectedLengthIs6_thenShouldThrowNotAnyArgumentException() {
    final SampleClass sample = new SampleClass("123456");
  }
}

Coverage:


You should migrate to JUnit 5! JUnit 5 offers significant improvements over its predecessors, making it a strong choice for modern Java testing.


The line final SampleClass sample = new SampleClass("1234567"); is still marked as not covered.

@Cardstdani what are you trying to check coverage of? Coverage is for the actual implementation, not for the test cases.

@Cardstdani I've added 2 test cases just to increase the coverage to 100%. However, you shan't rely on this metrics for reliability. COVERAGE LIES ABOUT THE QUALITY!

Or interpreted otherwise: coverage says nothing about reliability. @ZahidKhan You may look at your uncovered production code lines and consider whether there are some specific lines that you will want covered, You can use the coverage percentage for nothing. Nothing whatsoever that I know of.
